# How do I create a localtoworldmatrix and worldtolocalmatrix in Godot?

Tags: unity, matrix, transformation, godot, projection-matrix

From what I can tell Godot uses Projection for 4x4 matrixes, but I see no way to generate a localtoworldmatrix from a given transform in Godot, how do I do this?

Comment: [The Godot documentation seems to indicate that the `Transform3D` type *is* a matrix](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_transform3d.html#class-transform3d). It's the first 3 rows of a 4x4 matrix, the last row always being (0, 0, 0, 1) so they don't bother storing that part. [More details about matrix math can be found in the Godot docs here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/math/matrices_and_transforms.html).

Comment: @DMGregory Even then the equivalent to the localtoworldmatrix component is still unclear. Also I'm looking for the worldToCameraMatrix component as well. Regardless of whether that uses Projection or Transform3D, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Godot a `Transform3D` has no concept of local or world. They are transformations between spaces, and what those spaces are depend on how you use them.

For a concept of local or world space, we would have a `Node3D`. They expose two `Transform3D`:

- `Transform`: converts from local space to parent space (i.e. local space of the parent `Node3D`).
- `GlobalTransform`: converts from local space to world space.

Thus, if you want to convert a `Vector3` from local space of a `Node3D` to global space (world coordinates), you can multiply like this: `node.GlobalTransform * vector`.

For the opposite operation (global space to local space) you can get the inverse of the transform: `node.GlobalTransform.AffineInverse() * vector`.

However, we rarely do it like that, because `Node3D` has short hands for those operations: `to_global` and `to_local`.

So, if you have a `Camera3D` and you want to convert a `Vector3` from its local space to world space, you do this: `cam.to_global(vector)`.